What Oscilloscope to buy?
I recently made some posts on an issue I am having with executing a READ ID operation from an FPGA to a SPI Flash:

AT25SF081 SPI Flash FPGA issue narrow
AT25SF081 SPI Flash waveform timing verification

And am now in need of an 'scope' in order to debug my device.
This is the device I am using.
I am needing to test the SPI connections between the Flash and the FPGA to see if there is any error at the physical layer.
For context, I am a hobbyist and on a tight budget and I don't have much space. Basically it's a super resource constrained situation.
I would ideally like a handheld device.
How can I know what scopes are correct for my needs?

Specific product recommendations are 100% off-topic, so your question will be closed. I would suggest that in that price range you're better off getting a '24MHz' logic analyzer and open-source Sigrok.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany This is correct but depending on the nature of problem, it is hard to guess if the problem is in analog domain and better solved with a scope or in digital domain where it is better solved by a logic analyzer - the logic analyzer cannot see if there is an analog problem, like slow signals, overshooting and ringing causing glitches. However, a $5 logic analyzer in general is useful for any purpose so getting one might be a good idea regardless.

@Justme i can't imagine a 200kHz bandwidth MCU-based $18 'oscilloscope' is good for much with debugging an FPGA but I guess you could slow things down (but then the analog problems will be lost too).

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I have removed references to products - thanks

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Exactly my point as well - I thought all three products being useless for debugging this.

@Justme I guess the real answer is to borrow a multi-channel 400MHz oscilloscope and good probes.

You can first think what is your SPI bus signal speed, and the main clock of your FPGA at which everything happens. Generally SPI clocks may be between DC and FPGA speeds, and FPGAs can run at tens if not at hundreds of MHz.
Then compare if these devices with extremely low sampling rate and analog bandwith can even see the smallest possible glitches that may happen at the FPGA speed or even at th speed of the SPI clock.
